# Remove Cython assertion option in setup.py

Tags: python-3.x, cython

My Cython (`.pyx`) file contains `assert` and I would like to remove it when I compile the file. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4285513/4357279) and edited my `setup.py` as follows.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

# Before edit
compiler_args = ["-O3", "-ffast-math"]

# Both did not work
# compiler_args = ["-O3", "-ffast-math", "-DPYREX_WITHOUT_ASSERTIONS"]
# compiler_args = ["-O3", "-ffast-math", "-CYTHON_WITHOUT_ASSERTIONS"]

ext_modules = [
               Extension("mycython", sources=["mycython.pyx"],
               extra_compile_args=compiler_args)
              ]

setup(
      name="Test",
      cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
      ext_modules=ext_modules
     )
```

The error says:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-CYTHON_WITHOUT_ASSERTIONS'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: what do you mean by 'didn't work'?  may also get more help if you have a full reproducible example, including a pyx

Comment: @chrisb Thanks for pointing it out! I updated the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CYTHON_WITHOUT_ASSERTIONS` is a preprocessor macro, so you have to pass it to `clang` with the `-D` flag (just like `gcc`). The first variable's name is actually `PYREX_WITHOUT_ASSERTIONS`, but to pass it to the preprocessor as a macro (i.e. a part of your `clang` compiler) you need to add a `-D` in front of the variable name.

Try `compiler_args = ["-O3", "-ffast-math", "-DCYTHON_WITHOUT_ASSERTIONS"]` instead (note the `D` in front of `CYTHON_WITHOUT_ASSERTIONS`).

HTH.